# Please help me to understand this program

Tags: java

I have hard time to understand what the purpose of the for loop in this case is. It starts from 2 and repeats till the number we entered. Then it checks if the reminder of a/b is 0, if yes than "primeNumber == false". After that it exists the if sentence and checks the other if sentences. This is how i understood this program , if i am right why does the program show that 2 is a primenumber if 2/2 = 1 and therefore the reminder = 0.
Thank you

```
package prime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class primetime {
  public static void main (String [] agrs){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    boolean primeNumber = true;
    for ( int b = 2; b < a; b++){
        int z = a%b;
        if (z == 0){
            primeNumber = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (primeNumber == true){
        System.out.println("PrimZahl");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("keine PrimZahl");
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> why does the program show that 2 is a primenumber if 2/2 = 1 and therefore the reminder = 0

If `a==2`, the loop is never entered, since `b < a` is never true (because `b` is initialized to 2 and `2 < 2` is false). Therefore `primeNumber` remains `true`, as it should, since 2 is prime.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. What about 51?? 51/2 = 25.5 reminder is not 0 still shows me that 51 is not a primenumber which is true but how

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of something else !

Comment: @osman `51/3=17` so the remainder is 0. Hence 51 is not prime.

Comment: @Eran: That makes sense, thanks. What about 51?? 51/2 = 25.5 reminder is not 0 still shows me that 51 is not a primenumber which is true but how

Comment: @Eran : Where does the 3 come from?

Comment: @osman "A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself." so, it does not only be divided by 2 in order to return false. 3 is the value of `b` that perfectly divides 51 (which is `a`). So 51 is not a prime...

Comment: i think he is talking about even/odd numbers

Comment: @osman `b` iterates from 2 to `a`. so if `a` is 51, `b` will become `3` at some point and `a%b` will return 0.

Comment: I know what a prime number is, but in the code it looked like a is only divided by 2. So that's why the for loop is there? in order to divide the entered number not only by 2 but with other numbers?.

Comment: Thank you guys
appreciate it.